# How do i instantiate this inherited class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Ok this should be trivial, but i am stuck- the code is existing and should be fine.

```
 class Connect(object):
    def __init__(self, database, user, password, host, port):
        super(Connect, self).__init__()
        self.database = database
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

 class Process(Connect):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Process, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I can instantiate Connect easily

```
local_connection=Connect(database, user, password, host, port)
```

How do I instantiate Process?

If I do
`Process(database, user, password, host, port`) - 
Error is - TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)

If I do

```
Process(local_connection)
```

Error is - TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

If i try

```
Process()
```

Errorr is - TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I would tend to disagree with your assertion that the existing code is fine. The forwarding from `Process` to `Connect` is IMHO simply broken.

Comment: Why does `Process` only take `self` and `**kwargs`? Why not give it the same signature as the class it inherits from? Or positional `*args`?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was not correct .. but people have been using it for a while and I incorrectly assumed its probably fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this in two ways:

1. create a `Process`'s object along with argument's name as:

   ```
   >>> Process(database='database', user='user', password='password', host='host', port='port')
   <__main__.Process object at 0x7f4510150a10>
   ```
2. OR, Use `*args` along with `**kwargs` in `Process.__init__()` as:

   ```
   class Process(Connect):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(Process, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

   and just pass param to `__init__()` without arguments as:

   ```
   >>> Process('database', 'user', 'password', 'host', 'port')
   <__main__.Process object at 0x7f4510150950>
   ```

Please also refer: [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters) for knowing the difference between `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: Thank you anonymous

Comment: Use `*args` *in addition to* `**kwargs`, not instead of it.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, Updated it